# Create Record On Another Entity Dynamics 365 Plugin

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I have two entities. Let say: `MemberTransaction` and `MemberTransactionDetail`.
The case is: When creating new record on `MemberTransaction`. It will create a record also in `MemberTransactionDetail`.

The fields for each entity are:

`MemberTransaction`

```
MemberTransactionId PK,
MemberTransactionNo String,
TransactionDate DateTime,
MemberId LookUp
```

`MemberTransactionDetail`

```
MemberTransactionDetailId PK,
MemberTransactionId LookUp,
ProductId LookUp,
Qty number
```

Then I tried the following code:

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        try
        {
            var context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
            var postImage = context.PostEntityImages["PostImage"];
            var entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

            if (entity.Attributes.Contains("KEY"))
            {
                var memberTransactionId = postImage.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("trn_membertransactionid");
                var memberTransactionNo = postImage.GetAttributeValue<String>("trn_membertransactionno");

                var transactionDetail = new Entity("trn_membertransactiondetail");
                transactionDetail["trn_membertransactionno"] = memberTransactionNo;
                transactionDetail["trn_membertransactionid"] = new EntityReference("trn_membertransactiondetail", memberTransactionId);
                transactionDetail["trn_transactiondetailno"] = "6667";

                var serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
                var service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
                var tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

                tracingService.Trace("Plugin: Creating the Transaction Detail.");
                service.Create(transactionDetail);

                var transactionDetailId = transactionDetail.Id;
                tracingService.Trace("The Detail Id is " + transactionDetailId);
            }

            //var account = new Entity("account", memberTransactionId);
            //account["primarycontactid"] = new EntityReference("contact", transactionDetailId);
            //service.Update(account); // update the primary contact lookup
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write("What?" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The error said on the Exception is:
`The given key was not present in the dictionary.`

Does anyone can give me a solution for this matter please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

your issue is on below line. you are trying to set lookup filed but on entityreference you are giving `trn_membertransactiondetail` as entity name rather it should be enitity `MemberTransaction`.

```
transactionDetail["trn_membertransactionid"] = new EntityReference("trn_membertransactiondetail", memberTransactionId);
```

In addition are you sure, you will always get `memberTransactionId` by below line?

```
var memberTransactionId = postImage.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("trn_membertransactionid");
```

Comment: Hi @AnkUser, Thank you so much. I just learn d365 a few days ago. I don't really understand.

Comment: did you follow/understand what it means? for you Entity `trn_membertransactiondetail `field `trn_membertransactionid` you need to set lookup i.e record which is pointing to `MemberTransaction`

Comment: Hello, Yes sir. Thank you so much. I found the answer. I'll upload it. Cheers,